# Dynamically expand objects when rezising C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have designed a forms app in Visual Studio 2015 using C# where there are buttons, labels and text boxes inside of it and I was wondering how you make the buttons, labels and text boxes expand as you resize the app with the mouse?

I have tried using the anchor points but that only anchors the objects to the sides it does not resize them when you increase/decrease the size of the app. It just keeps them the same distance from the edge.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Dock and anchor controls or write code to resize.

Comment: You cannot dock and anchor the labels at the same time, you can only have one or the other.

Comment: I know, but if you know that, then what are you asking here?

Comment: Because they don't resize it. So I am asking how you get them to expand with the app when you resize it.
Also not very helpful to say just write code!!
You could say that to almost every question posted on here, but does that help anyone? No it does not, that is why people ask questions as they need help!!

Comment: I have tried using the anchor points but that only anchors the objects to the sides it does not resize them when you increase/decrease the size of the app <== this is actually incorrect, anchors can anchor to all sized, and resize

Comment: So I anchored it to all sides but it doesn't resize even with AutoSize set to True.

Comment: You want `AutoSize` set to `False` on a label - the `AutoSize` property resizes the label's width to its contents, not its container. Also, resizing a label to its container sounds like a bad idea.